# Not possible to accept only TLS 1.2 with boost::asio?

Tags: ssl, openssl, boost-asio, libtorrent

So I am trying to modify a third party (libtorrent) to only accept the TLS 1.2 protocol.

Part of the setup of the SSL context:

```
boost::shared_ptr<context> ctx = boost::make_shared<context>(boost::ref(m_ses.get_io_service()), context::tlsv12)

ctx->set_options(context::default_workarounds
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1_1
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
```

However when I am testing my connection with OpenSSL s_client it still seems to accept tls 1.0 and tls 1.1 connection.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Added "| boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1_1" to options. I realized I was referring to an old boost reference guide. It did however not change anything.

EDIT: I just realize that I have not mentioned that this connection is a two-way/mutual authentication connection. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: You need to show more code. Specifically, how you're making sure your ctx is applied to all connections

Comment: I am not sure how to show you that In a good way. But let's assume this is applied to all connections, is this code correct?

Comment: I think so. The point is, there's too many things that can be wrong other than this to even start thinking. See [nobody writes test cases anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/). Make it into a SSCCE and you might spot the problem yourself. Otherwise, we are here to cross check

Comment: I guess that would have to be my next step. I was hoping to not having to dig to deep into the third party lib ;)

Comment: What third party lib?

Comment: https://github.com/libtorrent/libtorrent

Comment: Ahahahaha. Best to add that to your question then. Does you `ctx` thing modify existing library code, or does a library call _take_ the ctx? Is there a sample you can link to?

Comment: This is the library code that I am modyfing.  I have changed two things in the code: the input method to the constructor changed from sslv23 to tlsv12 and no_sslv3 and no_tlsv1 is added to the options. That's it. I am just assuming the lib is using this ctx for all connections.

Comment: Seems a fair assumption. Would have been clear from the beginning if you said "I modified line ### of ?????.cpp to read:"

Comment: @jimmy - what are you seeing with `s_client` or the server that leads you to believe any version of TLS is accepted (please forgive my ignorance).

Comment: first, you may want to try: http://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent (the link you posted is a very stale mirror). second, you may want to test boost.asio's example programs using SSL to see if you can make those only accept TLS 1.2

Comment: @jww I don't have much experience with s_client but what I see is that when I use tls1 , tls1.1 and tls1.2 s_client will show me the certificates of the "server" as well as which ciphers were used. When I use SSL3 it will fail the handshake and tell me it used chipher: (None)

Comment: @Arvid I am actually using the code from the source you mention. I posted my previous comment from my phone and did a quick google to get the link, apparently I got it wrong. :)

Comment: @Arvid I will have a look at boost:asio example code to see if it is possible.

Comment: @jimmy we need more details because this thread so far is based solely on comments of perceived issues by you. I have a HTTPS capable proxy that I restrict to TLS 1.2 using boost 1.58 and while I do get clients connecting attempting to use things like SSL3, those connections fail. You're doing something wrong and you need to post more code.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I am not sure what parts of the code would make sense to show without making it way to much. As I mentioned earlier this is just minor modifications I have done to an existing library. You are more than welcome to have a look in the source  github.com/arvidn/libtorrent . The code in question is located in Torrent.cpp around line 1600.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire When I am testing the connection with openssl s_client I also see that SSLv3 is restricted, however TLS1 and TLS1.1 is not. Have you ever tested for those two in particular?

Comment: @jimmy no I haven't actually. My recommendation to you is to create a simple program for testing purposes because TBH, no one is going to pour over libtorrents code to help you find your answer. I am intrigued by your question now, but you currently don't have a minimal example to test with and I'm personally not intrigued enough to create one. :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I honestly didn't expect anyone to actually have a look in  the libtorrent code, that was just the only thing I have until I have time to make a simpler test setup.

Comment: @jimmy I posted an answer that may or not help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81503/discussion-between-technik-empire-and-jimmy).

Answer (score 1):

There is no constant for TLS1.2 in asio::ssl::context. But you can use native openssl API to do that:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
long ssl_disallowed = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2;
ssl_disallowed &= ~SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx.native_handle(), ssl_disallowed);
```

Comment: Since boost 1.58 there is actually constants for TLS1.2 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a total shot in the dark, but try this:

Try creating a string of ciphers specific to TLS 1.2 and then call

```
char* TLS_12_CIPHERS = "... list of ciphers specific to TLS 1.2";
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx->native_handle(), TLS_12_CIPHERS);
```

Then set the option on the context (assuming it's a server context) that the server gets to choose what ciphers it wants use, not client.

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx->native_handle(), SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE);
```

You'd think that boost::asio::ssl would take care of this stuff for you by specifying the no_X options but I can't be sure. Like I said this is a shot in the dark, but explicitly configuring context using the OpenSSL API in this way should enforce the conditions you're after. Even if somewhere, somehow, some conflicting option is being set to allow non TLS 1.2 connections, with these options, any non TLS 1.2 connection will fail with the error "no shared cipher".

As for why your server is even advertising that non 1.2 connections are acceptable is unknown, but one possible explanation is that there is a default context that is advertising this. This is why sehe made the point about "applying to all connections."

[Here is a list](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#TLS-v1.2-cipher-suites) of TLS 1.2 specific ciphers.